# Condition for product of tow rectangular matirx is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, svd

Let $A$ and $b$ be $m \times n$ matrices, it seems the product $A'B$ is diagonalizable only if  $A$ and $B$ share the same left and right singularvectors.  Is it true ?.  How can I prove it, in case it is true ?

Comment: Have you considered the case where $n = m$, $A$ is the identity, and $B$ is any non-identity diagonal matrix?

Comment: @JohnHughes, I did not get the comment in the full sense.  For the case you mentioned, the left and right eigenvectors are same. So the condition holds true right ?. In fact product of any two commutable normal matrix is also normal right ?

Comment: "For the case you mentioned, the left and right eigenvectors are same." No, they're not. For instance, if $B = \pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3}$, then $\pmatrix{1\\1}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ (the identity, for which all vectors are eigenvectors), but not an eigenvector of $B$.

Comment: @JohnHughes, you take the svd of I and B, and both the left eigenvectors and right eigenvectors for I and B are same. At least, I can tell you that numpy gives it as same.  Also (1,1) is not an eigenvector

Comment: I believe that you need to study up on the definition of eigenvector. It's **not** defined by what some procedure in numpy produces. Also note: the SVD of the identity matrix is not unique: $I = Q^t I Q$ is **a** singular value decomposition when $Q$ is any orthogonal matrix. For instance, if $s = \sqrt{2}/2$, then $Q = \pmatrix{s & s \\ -s & s}$ gives a singular value decomposition for the identity which is different from the one that numpy produces.

Comment: @JohnHughes, I agree that it is not unique.  But in the specific example you mentioned, we can find common set of eigenvectors right ?.  Are you saying that the eigenvectors I mentioned is not correct ?

Comment: @JohnHughes, may be I should clearly mention that both matrices should share a common set of left and right eigenvectors. That makes more sense ?.  In that case, is there a proof available ?

Comment: Your question says "only if $A$ and $B$ have the same left and right eigenvectors." I gave an example where the set of eigenvectors of $A$ (namely, all vectors) and those of $B$ (namely $e_1$ and $e_2$) are distinct. So what you wrote in your question is wrong. Your later claim that $\pmatrix{1\\1}$ is not an eigenvector of the identity matrix is also wrong. If you want to ask a different question, in light of these two, feel free. But I'm not chasing down a chameleon question.

Comment: Non square matrices have no eigenvectors of any persuasion (left or right). To me it is not clear what the question even wants to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it does not make sense to talk about eigenvalues unless $m=n$.

Second, consider the following example
$$
A=\pmatrix{2&1\\2&-1},
B = A\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} = \pmatrix{1&2\\-1&2},
$$
then
$$
A^TB = \pmatrix{4&0\\0&-4},$$
which is clearly diagonalizable. However, $A$ and $B$ do not share any left or right eigenvector, as $\pmatrix{1\\1}$ is no eigenvector of these matrices.